# Return key from TextField to TextView

Tags: ios, swift, textview, textfield

I jump from `textField` to `textView` by:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == self.someTextField {
            self.someTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
        } 
    return true
}
```

It works, but my `textView` starts with return, I mean from second line.

How to fix it?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a newline added in `xib`.

Comment: when i tap textView first, it is fine

Comment: Ok that is interesting, the code you are showing here doesn't show any sign of that. May be the return that you hit to take you out of `textField` and also get register on `textView`. Check that by adding breakpoint on `textView` delegate.

Comment: Yeah, lots of magic is going around the SO these days.

Comment: yea, it jumps over the `textView.text` and starts from new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `return false` in `if statement`:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == self.someTextField {
            self.someTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
            return false
        } 
    return true
}
```